# ZSH setopt PROMPT_SUBST not working

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to get customize my zsh prompt and want to evaluation a function with git commands every time my prompt is generated. I'm using `setopt PROMPT_SUBST`, but it doesn't seem to be working. This is my zshrc:

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
autoload -U colors && colors # Enable colors

# Show Git branch/tag, or name-rev if on detached head
parse_git_branch() {
  echo "PARSING GIT BRANCH"
  (git symbolic-ref -q HEAD || git name-rev --name-only --no-undefined --always HEAD) 2> /dev/null
}

prompt() {
    echo -n "%/"
    echo "$(git status)"
}

PS1="$(prompt)"
```

And this is my output of `setopt`:

```
interactive
login
monitor
nonomatch
promptsubst
shinstdin
zle
```

Comment: This is **purely** a zsh question. bash has no place in either title or tagging. Please do not tag for other shells unless you're completely certain your question applies to both (tested code against both, got an identical result) -- the immediate quoting bug applies to bash, but your reproducer wouldn't work there for other reasons.

Comment: BTW -- using parens for grouping is quite inefficient. Better to use braces: `{ git symbolic-ref -q HEAD || git name-rev --name-only --no-undefined --always HEAD; } 2>/dev/null` -- that way you aren't incurring subshell overhead.

Answer (score 10):

You need to delay calling `prompt` until the prompt is displayed; do that by using single quotes:

```
PS1='$(prompt)'
```

A better idea, though, is to define a function that sets `PS1`, then add that function to the `precmd_functions` array so that it is executed prior to displaying each prompt.

```
prompt () {
    PS1="%/$(git status)"
}

precmd_functions+=(prompt)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the difference between ' and ". What exactly does it mean to delay calling something?

Comment: @George, single-quotes suppress shell expansions, so the `$()` becomes part of the value stored in PS1. By contrast, inside double quotes, what's actually stored in PS1 is the output of running the command a single time immediately.

Comment: With single quotes, `PS1` is set to the literal string `$(prompt)`, not the result of calling `prompt`. The prompt variables are special, though; when they are displayed, they undergo another round of evaluation, so `$(prompt)` is expand each time the prompt is shown.